# Making sense of a Rational Rose class diagram

Tags: uml, rational-rose

I'm looking at a UML class diagram that is made using Rational rose and there are some symbols I don't recognize.

For example, beside an attribute, there is a blue square with a lock on it. Does this mean it is private? But beside an operation there is a purple square with a lock? What is the difference between a lock with a purple square and a blue square.

I can't seem to find a legend for a rational rose diagram using using Google, this is fairly frustrating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This tutorial might help: [Rational Rose Tutorial](http://www.docstoc.com/docs/2146683/Rational-Rose-Tutorial). Check slides 22 and 25 for visibility icons illustrations.

Answer (score 2):

Some of Rational Rose's diagrams are extremely code-oriented, even more so than UML itself. Those icons you are referring to are not part of the standard UML. They depict some properties that the different diagrams elements (attributes, for example) are supposed to have when translated into (Java) code. The Rational Rose documentation should help.